# how expired OAuth2 Tokens are detected?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm a beginner in Spring Boot and I set up OAuth2 and all work well with inMemory () data.
I'm trying to store the Token in DB but I want the client to stay in memory because I will always use a single client for this application
so i created the necessary tables using [schema.sql](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql) i see that only the oauth_access_token and oauth_refresh_token tables that will be used and when i make a request to request a token the system returns the old one if it is still valid and a new one if not(this is good but..). For this reason I have difficulty understanding how the system can know that a token is expired or not? (knowing that I do not define JWT token or any other specific type of token explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

The token in this scenario is an instance of class DefaultOAuth2AccessToken which has field

> expiration

which takes care of expiry of a token. Object of this class is serialized so that it can be stored in database.Upon deserialization values are populated in respective fields and below method is invoked to check for expiry.

```
   public boolean isExpired() {
    return this.expiration != null && this.expiration.before(new Date());
}
```

The class DefaultTokenServices has createAccessToken() method  to create token.
just go and have a look at these classes to see the working.

Comment: what I don't understand is how Spring comes to know that the token is expired or not (even after restarting the application, to make sure that the data will not be stored in memory) while at the level of my database I do not see anything that can result in deducing the expiry date of the token

Comment: in database the object is stored in serialized form. Do you see random values in your table columns ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer 
After some research in the documentation i can now understand how the token is validated.
the token (DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) is stored as a serialized object in the DB and it will be retrieved from the database to validate expiration date , and many other operation ...